# How to use dodirect payment paypal on form submission?

Tags: forms, payment-gateway, paypal, submission

I have to use dodirect payment method after the form submission. The form will be displayed on the site for all the card detail such as card type (visa or master), card card no, security number, expiration date, name on card, address, state, postal, country, phone, email etc.

I searched how to use the dodirect method and found as below

```
<?php

/** DoDirectPayment NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Process a credit card payment. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
    $API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');              // or 'Sale'
$firstName = urlencode('customer_first_name');
$lastName = urlencode('customer_last_name');
$creditCardType = urlencode('customer_credit_card_type');
$creditCardNumber = urlencode('customer_credit_card_number');
$expDateMonth = 'cc_expiration_month';
// Month must be padded with leading zero
$padDateMonth = urlencode(str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$expDateYear = urlencode('cc_expiration_year');
$cvv2Number = urlencode('cc_cvv2_number');
$address1 = urlencode('customer_address1');
$address2 = urlencode('customer_address2');
$city = urlencode('customer_city');
$state = urlencode('customer_state');
$zip = urlencode('customer_zip');
$country = urlencode('customer_country');               // US or other valid country code
$amount = urlencode('example_payment_amuont');
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr =   "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
            "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
            "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoDirectPayment', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('Direct Payment Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else  {
    exit('DoDirectPayment failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

?>
```

I didn't get an idea how to use this code on submission of the form that I have on my site. Can anyone help me out how to use this after submitting form.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really not a very well built function.  It's basically wanting you to just fill in the values within the function rather than pass them in.  It's a pretty rough example and you can see it was last updated in 2008 according to the comments.

If you want to use it, though, you can simply fill in all those placeholders where they show things like "my_api_username" with the data that you want to actually include.

If you want something a lot easier to work with, I would recommend using this [PHP library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) that I developed and have maintained for years.  It's current and contains straight forward samples for running DoDirectPayment.  You could have it up-and-running within minutes.

I offer 30 min of free training via screen share, too, if you're interested in that.

Comment: Is this payment safe? Will the users do this payment because sites can track the credit card information of the user and that may be miss used? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are samples available for DoDirectPayment as part of the official SDKs available at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew

Suggest using the official SDK and check the samples inside them. In case of any issues please post back here or open an issue at https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/issues

Comment: The PayPal provided SDK's leave a lot to be desired, unfortunately.

Comment: Andrew, We will be glad to work on the desired features that are needed for the PHP SDK if you can list them. We did some major revamp a month ago. Please add your comments or issues at https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/issues